# Powermock failed to find the 'modifiers' field in method setInternalState

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to run java test cases. Its a spring boot application. When we run the test classes we get "**java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error: Failed  to find the 'modifiers' field in method setInternalState.**"

Below are the version details

```
java version - 17
spring-boot - 2.3.2.RELEASE
project.build.sourceEncoding - UTF-8
projectlombok.version - 1.18.22
org.apache.maven.plugins.version - 3.6.0
azure-storage-blob - 12.22.2
junit - 4.12
```

Please help.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3 does not support Java 17 - you need to upgrade to at least Spring Boot 2.5 if you want to use Java 17.

Comment: And note that even Spring Boot 2.5 is already past end-of-life (https://endoflife.date/spring-boot). IMHO you should update to Spring Boot 3.x as soon as possible (with Spring Boot 2.7 as an intermediate step to ease migration.)